# Unexpected Behaviour with List in C++

Tags: c++

I was writing a program for Euler circuit, but the program didn't give the right output.

Adding a seemingly unrelated line of code got it to work. Can someone decode what just happened?

Snippet of the original program:

```cpp
/* A is a vector of lists that, where A[i] is the list of edges from vertex i. */
/* perform checks for even degree, then find a non-isolated vertex to begin the tour */
int u;
for (u = 0; u < A.size() && A[u].empty(); u++)
while (!A[u].empty()) {
    cout << u << "->";
    int v = A[u].front();
    A[u].pop_front();
    u = v;
}
cout << u << endl;
```

The line that I added after the end of for loop:

```cpp
cout << u << A[u].size() << endl;
```

Comment: "Adding a seemingly unrelated line of code got it to work" is a strong indicator of undefined behavior, possibly somewhere not actually in your snippet at all. I'm pretty confused by this snippet, because you have `A[u].empty()` as a condition in your `for` loop and then `!A[u].empty()` in your while loop so I don't understand why you think this would do anything at all.

Comment: *Adding a seemingly unrelated line of code got it to work* -- Remove that line of code and actually fix the problem.  By putting that line in the code, you've moved the bug to another part of the program.  The best thing is to always be able to replicate the problem, not mask it or move it somewhere else.

Comment: @NathanPierson A[u].empty() in the for loop is to skip the isolated vertices i.e. an empty list of outgoing egdes; and !A[u].empty() in the while loop is for exhausting all possible edges of the non-isolated vertex.

Comment: `Snippet of the original program:` -- Please post a [mcve].

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie _Remove that line of code and actually fix the problem._ How? The while loop doesn't even execute without that line, for some reason.

Comment: Are the `for` and the `while` loop supposed to be taking place one after the other? As written the `while` loop takes place inside the `for` loop.

Comment: @ihsingh2 -- Did you read my comment completely?  You haven't fixed anything by putting that line in there.  Remove it, debug the code.  Again, by putting that line in there, the bug is somewhere else, or worse, has been hidden, and who knows when or where it will show up again.

Comment: @NathanPierson Thanks!! Forgot the semicolon, sorry for this stupid thread.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let me rewrite your snippet with more accurate indentation and some braces added for clarity:

```cpp
int u;
for (u = 0; u < A.size() && A[u].empty(); u++)
{
    while (!A[u].empty()) {
        cout << u << "->";
        int v = A[u].front();
        A[u].pop_front();
        u = v;
    }
}
cout << u << endl;
```

Notice that the `while` loop is *inside* the `for` loop. But if we're in the `for` loop, then `A[u].empty()` is true, so `!A[u].empty()` is false, so the `while` loop is never entered.

When you added a line "after" the `for` loop, you made that one line what the `for` loop executes:

```cpp
int u;
for (u = 0; u < A.size() && A[u].empty(); u++)
{
    cout << u << A[u].size() << endl;
}
while (!A[u].empty()) {
    cout << u << "->";
    int v = A[u].front();
    A[u].pop_front();
    u = v;
}
cout << u << endl;
```

Now, you have the intended behavior: A `for` loop that increments `u`, followed by a separate `while` loop that acts on `u`.

To get the original behavior while still having the first `for` loop do nothing, actually give your `for` loop an empty body:

```cpp
int u;
for (u = 0; u < A.size() && A[u].empty(); u++) { }
while (!A[u].empty()) {
    cout << u << "->";
    int v = A[u].front();
    A[u].pop_front();
    u = v;
}
cout << u << endl;
```

Comment: What do you mean I can't have `A[u].empty() && !A[u].empty()` -- `:)` (good catch!)